# How to restrict edit option and some pages

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.net

I have a differenct users in my software (Windows based application), i want to give the access according to the user rights..

For Example

```
Admin Login can able to access and edit all the forms
User Login can able to limited access to edit and view the forms
Employee login can able to view the forms only
...
```

....

Can any one give some ideas or sample code for this...

Need Vb.Net Help

Comment: This is too vague - we can only deal with specific problems here

Answer (score 0):

You use the Authorize attribute to accomplish this in MVC.

[Authorize Attribute on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)